# Difference between 上、のみならず、ばかりか

Tags: grammar, jlpt

I was doing some JLPT N@ practice, and I got this question wrong:

> 留学中は日本の言語や文学を学ぶ（　）、自分の国のことも伝えていこうと考えている。
>
> a 上
>
> b のみならず
>
> c ばかりか

I chose "a" while the correct answer is "b". According to my book, all three answer seem correct.

My book says that (only quoting the relevant parts):

> 〜上
>
> 前後には同じ評価の言葉が来る。
>
> 〜のみならず
>
> 「に限らず」と違って、同じレベルの他のものも同様だという場合にも使える。
>
> 〜ばかりか
>
> 〜だけでも十分なのに、さらに他のことも加わる。前の文で普通ではないことを言い、さらに後の文でも意外性を感じさせるのかのことを加える。

I thought it boils down to whether the former and latter half of the sentence are "at the sane level" or not, If they are, then 上 or のみならず. If the latter half is more "surprising" than the first half, then ばかりか. But still, why のみならず instead of 上?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What follows 上 must be greater things in the same field. e.g. 日本の言語や文学を学ぶ上（に）JLPT合格も目指す / 数学も学ぶ. In this regard, のみならず is versatile.

Comment: I basically agree with your answer, but can you please explain further when 上（に）would apply but not のみならず? I think doing so will help the asker better understand. As for myself, 上（に）just doesn't feel right in the above example. I'm guessing the ～う form of the verb（学ぶ）has something to do with it. If it were ～が学べる、then 上（に）could apply.

Comment: (continuation) By the way ～伝えていこう should also be ～伝えていける in order for 上（に）to work in the above example, like this: 留学中は日本の言語や文学が学べる上（に）、自分の国のことも伝えていけると考えている。Just my guess.ネイティブの方に確認していただけると幸いです。